# convert utf-8 characters to HTML named entities

Tags: html, utf-8, xhtml

I am searching for a quick solution to the following problem. I hope there is something available out of the box, however I haven't found it yet.

I have a bunch of utf-8 encoded xHTML files that contain some non-ASCII symbols like French and German letters and special punctuation. I need to recode the files to Cp1251 aka Cyrillic Windows, but in order to preserve these letters and symbols, I need to represent them as HTML named character references. At the same time, the rest of HTML should remain unchanged. The question is what do I use for this purpose?

I am running Ubuntu and my current solution is based on bash and standard Linux tools like sed, grep, ... Plus tidy and xsltproc.

Thank you in advance!

Best regards,
Vlad

Comment: Why would you do this – for HTML files? UTF-8 is the recommended encoding for HTML.

Comment: Right, but the site is big and this is one of migration steps. It is not possible to stick with utf-8 at the moment, hence the question.